# How to break out of a while loop with a boolean?

Tags: c++, while-loop, nested, boolean, n-queens

I am trying to break out of several nested while loops and I am having trouble. I want this program to break out into the outer loop, which will run only a certain amount of times. I tried doing it with a boolean but my program terminates too early. It is an N-Queens problem where I am solving for 1x1, 2x2, 3x3,...nxn queens.

Here is my code:

```
bool ok(int *q, int col)
{
   for(int i=0; i<col; i++)
      if(q[col]==q[i] || (col-i)==abs(q[col]-q[i])) return false;

return true;
};

void print(int q[], int n, int cnt)
{
    //static int count =0;
    cout<<"There are "<<cnt<<" solutions for "<<n<<" queens." <<endl;   
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    int *q;
    cout<<"Please enter the size of the board:"<<endl;
    cin>>n;

    int static count = 0;

    int c = 1;
    int a = 1;
    bool from_backtrack=false;

    while(a!=n){

        q= new int[a];
        q[0]=0;
        bool foundSolution=true;
        while(foundSolution)
        {
            if (c==a){
                a++;
            }
            while(c<a)
            {
                if(!from_backtrack)
                    q[c] = -1; //Start at the top
                from_backtrack=false;
                while(q[c]<a)
                {
                    q[c]++;
                    if  (q[c]==a)
                    {
                        c--;
                        if(c==-1) {
                            print(q, n, count);
                            foundSolution=false;
                            //system("PAUSE"); exit(1);
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    if( ok(q,c) ) break; //get out of the closest while loop
                }
                c++;
            }
            count++;
            c--;
            if(c==-1) {
                print(q, n, count);
                foundSolution=false;
                //system("PAUSE"); exit(1);
            }
            from_backtrack=true;
        }
        delete[a] q;
        a++;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us what "too early" means.  I would focus on the condition expressions you wrote for the `break` statement.

Comment: while(foundSolution = true)
        { --Possible bug

Comment: it can be done using goto, but this is frowned upon. You can very likely refactor your code so you won't have to break out of multiple levels.

Comment: extract some functions

Comment: To break out of multiple levels you could use try with catches and throw an exception in the inner loops.

Comment: I think you want to re factor this stuff out.. full of bugs and not clear what you are trying to do :(

Comment: Alright, I'll try to break these into smaller peices, because this program is overwhelming me.

Comment: Start with fixing the compilation issues (undefined symbols including  `print`, `ok`, `q`), and Lews` first hint is important, as it is likely the source of evil in itself. Use `while (foundSolution)` for that specific issue.

Comment: I edited my program to show the undefined symbols (they are functions) and edited that while loop Lews pointed out was wrong. This is an N-Queens problem, basically, but I am trying to make it solve for 1-N solutions (the user inputs N).

Comment: Personally at four layers of indentation I start to question my logic and code structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most elegant way would be to wrap some of your inner loops in a function. 
It will be easier to read and to control.

Answer (score 0):

At my work, we employ MISRA guidelines which state "... only 1 break per while loop".  This has caused me to rewrite my `if` and `while` loops:

```
bool can_continue = true;

if (can_continue)
{
  status = Do_Something();
  if (status != SUCCESS)
  {
    can_continue = false;
  }
}

if (can_continue)
{
  status = Do_Another_Thing();
  can_continue = status == SUCCESS;
}

//.. and so on.
```

The idea is to set a flag to "false" if execution can't continue.  Check it after any segment can cause execution to fail.

Answer (score -1):

```
while( true ){

    if( condition == true ){
        goto bye;
    }
}

:bye
```

Just don't submit this on your homework...

Comment: "Just don't submit this on your homework" - what kind of software do you recommend this approach for in that case? High availability website backends? Financial trading? Aviation control?

Comment: I.e.: If it isn't good enough for homework in your opinion, why would you recommend using it at all?

Comment: I tried that out just to see if it would work. I get a HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED error.

Comment: @Chase Don't ever use `goto`, not even in jest. [Bad things will happen.](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/goto.png).

Comment: The "goto bye;" can be replaced by a `break`.

Comment: @EdwardA: There are valid use cases for goto, but I agree that they are far and few between.

Comment: @Edward Shame on you for linking directly to an XKCD image file - the mouseovers are often the best part!

Answer (score -1):

Think it is as crazy as useless.

However, suppose you want 3 iterations, you'll define an array of bool of 3 elements (all set to true). On each iteration you set the current element to false, until you reach the end of your array.